# Displaying a user's password in plaintext on login pages. Why is this practice becoming more widespread?

Tags: passwords, account-security

Over the years I've noticed that more and more login pages implement an eye icon next to the password field, that on click toggles between hidden and plaintext view of the password typed in that field.

Why is this feature becoming more widespread? Why would various companies spend time, effort and money implementing a feature that increases the risk of account hijacking?

Comment: I think you are over-stating the *general* risk. The benefit is that it can prevent accounts getting locked out by simple mistakes. The risk is that for a split second, a valid password might be shown.

Comment: Most of the time the eye icon is either implemented by the browser (for a standard HTML password box), or the HTML/CSS framework. In either of those cases, it is usually pretty free to "enable" it, and most of the time it needs additional work just to disable it.